# Use Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown toggle to trigger another dropdown toggle or div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I need to make a dropdown toggle with some options, and when the user selects one of those options from dropdown, it either triggers another dropdown toggle to appear right underneath OR Call a Div and display some content.

I have looked at the BS documentation and they don't really go into the triggers or what's needed to call another div or dropdown to display.

Here's [a link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahils1802/GWUQr/3/) on what I have.

I want the second dropdown to only appear when user selects "Option 1" from previous dropdown toggle.

```
<div class="question">
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Select one                    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="opt1" >Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="opt2">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="opt3">Option 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="opt3">Option 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="question">
  <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Another One                    <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="opt5" >Option 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="opt6">Option 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="opt7">Option 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="opt8">Option 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to do it.

```
$('.question .visitor li:first-child a').click(function () { // First li of it's parent
            $('.opt1').fadeToggle();
        });
```

OR

```
$('.question .visitor li:eq(0) a').click(function () { // 0 is the first of all relevant elements criteria 
            $('.opt1').fadeToggle();
        });
```

OR

```
$('#opt1').click(function () { // Select by ID
            $('.opt1').fadeToggle();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll need to detect a click event on the dropdown box in question, on an `<li>` if you want that to be the trigger.  So:

```
$( "ul.dropdown-menu li" ).click(function() {

});
```

Now, whenever an `<li>` is clicked inside the dropdown-menu, that callback function will be called.  Here, if you need another dropdown or a div to appear, use the `appendChild()` method to add those items where needed.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand, and you need each `<li>` cause a different item to appear.  In this case, try:

    `$("ul.dropdown-menu li:eq(0)").click(function() {`
        `// now you can control what happens when you click the first`
        `// dropdown element.  Replace the `0` with `1` for the`
        `// second, `2` for the third, etc`
    `});`